# Why is my function not reading to my EventListener?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, addeventlistener

i'm trying to do something with an element when i click on it. I putted this eventListener so it changes the value of a variable when i click on that element.

But it doesn't work, and when i check with debugger the function is not even getting inside of the eventListener, it just completely ignores it and i don't get errors in the console, why does this happen??

my code:

````
markAsRead(articleid) {
            debugger
    //there is three different "X", and i needed to get the three of them
            let mainNode = document.querySelectorAll('.markasread')[0];
            let firstNode = document.querySelectorAll('.markasread')[1];
            let secondNode = document.querySelectorAll('.markasread')[2];
    
            firstNode.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
                
                this.$parent.markingAsRead = false;
                this.isLoading = false;
                console.log('test 1')
                
            });
            secondNode.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
               
                this.$parent.markingAsRead = false;
                this.isLoading = false;
                console.log('test 2')
            });

            this.isLoading = true;
            this.$parent.markingAsRead = true;
            
            this.$eventBus.$emit('articleRemove', (articleid));
            this.titleAcross = '';   

            
        }, ```

I'm using Vue.js, btw
````

Comment: a minimal reproducible example or complete code snippet is needed will usually be a dom lifecycle unreproducible error

Answer (score -1):

querySelector and querySelectorAll are usually not the way to go in VueJS, if you want to select something. Either bind with state or use a template reference.